# In Keras, Unable to save model checkpoints when using Lambda in model. Give error ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Tags: keras, nlp, checkpoint

In Keras, I am unable to save model checkpoints when using Lambda in the model. It gives a Value error:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

The code is as below

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(MAX_NUM_WORDS,
               EMBEDDING_DIM,
               weights=[embedding_matrix],
               input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
               trainable=False))

model1.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(300, activation='relu')))
#model1.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(300,)))
model1.add(Lambda(lambda x: func(x), output_shape=(300,)))

model1_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32', 
                     name='model1_input')

model1_output = model1(model1_input)
```

As per a few suggestions on net, I used Lambda in Sequential API and then used Functional API.
Pls help

Answer (score 0):

In order to save your model, the function used in your Lambda (`func`) must be serializable. Depending on its complexity it can be tricky, if it is not already the case, you should try to avoid using constants or variables defined outside of the function.

Comment: could you pls guide me, how to serialize below function

Comment: model1.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(300,)). I created function and then used it as below
def func(x):
   x = K.sum(x,axis=1)
   return x

model1.add(Lambda(lambda x: func(x), output_shape=(300,)))